# Asp.net Master page navigation with content pages

Tags: c#, asp.net, twitter-bootstrap, uinavigationbar

I have a master page design with the following structure:

```
main.master
index.aspx
    folder A
      indexa.aspx
    folder B
      indexb.aspx
    folder C
      indexc.aspx
```

when i run the app, the index.aspx is the default page . From that page i want to navigate between all the pages. Ex. navigate from the **index.aspx** to **indexa.aspx** and from **indexa.aspx** to **indexc.aspx**, and so on. but actually i am getting resource not found

```
   <div class="navbar-right">
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li>
            <a href="~/../folder A/indexa.aspx">
            </a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="~/../folder C/indexb.aspx">
            </a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="~/../folder C/indexc.aspx" >
            </a>
        </li>
       </ul>
  </div>

 <ul class="sidebar-menu">
        <li class="active">
            <a href="../index.aspx">
            </a>
        </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: why are you saying "one folder behind the project root/folder A/"?

Comment: in the root directory , i created 3 folders to group my work, folder A,B, and C. Each folder has its content pages from the main master page named main. @Kritner

Comment: remove ../ and just use ~/folderA/indexa.aspx

Comment: "~" implies root unless I am mistaken.  If you goto root, then back a directory, then into folder A, that does not match that information you typed out if your structure

Comment: @Kritner one folder behind the project root , it is to get back to the main index.aspx page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your structure:

```
C:/projects/
    main.master
    index.aspx
    folder A/
      indexa.aspx
    folder B/
      indexb.aspx
    folder C/
      indexc.aspx
```

The URL 
    "~/../folder A/indexa.aspx" 
would take you to 
    "C:/folder A/indexa.aspx"

You want 
    "~/folder A/indexa.aspx"

to take you to
    "C:/projects/folder a/indexa.aspx"

From my understanding however, you need to use a server control for "~" to work properly. [use of tilde (~) in asp.net path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3077558/use-of-tilde-in-asp-net-path)

Comment: i got it , i was not using the asp.net server controls. thanks