# What does PathTemplate.StartsWith("~/entityset") exactly do in Odata Web API Routing

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, odata

I can't figure out what this code does.

```
public override string SelectController(ODataPath odataPath, HttpRequestMessage request)
{
    return odataPath != null &&
           odataPath.PathTemplate.StartsWith("~/entityset", 
                                  StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) ? "A" : null;
}
```

I know the syntactic meaning, but what does `StartsWith("~/entityset"` do ?

The problem is `~/entityset`. I have no reference of what this entity set is and where is it taken from. I guess it could represent some entity set , which one ?

Is it some default OData mechanish to check URLs?

Comment: I would look at OdataPath.PathTemplate configuration on your middleware. Also can be that someone changed the "~/entityset" to be "A".

Comment: @Bart Middleware ? I am using EF to create model and then the standard SelectController and SelectAction functions in my routing.

Comment: Possibly relevant: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3077558/use-of-tilde-in-asp-net-path

Comment: Take a look on Startup.cs and/or ODataConfiguration files.

Comment: btw, this *may* help: http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/odata-support-in-aspnet-web-api/odata-routing-conventions

Answer (score 1):

This is used to decide on the routing within OData. Here some example URLs and what their path templates would be that all start with ~/entityset

http://localhost/odata/Students

```
"~/entityset"
```

http://localhost/odata/Students(1)

```
"~/entityset/key"
```

http://localhost/odata/Students(1)/Teachers

```
"~/entityset/key/navigation"
```

To find out which entity set it is you can look at the segments making up the path

```
((EntitySetPathSegment)request.ODataProperties().Segments.First()).EntitySetName
```

Segments.First() won't necessarily be a EntitySetPathSegment unless the path starts with ~/entityset so make sure you make that check first.