# How to make simple web navigation?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am new to web development, and what I am trying to do is a simple back-forward navigation using hyperlinks.

In main page I have the link to the second page like this:

```
<a href="/development/html/test2.aspx">This is the LINK to the second page</a>
```

and then in this second page, I have a link that points back to the main page like this:

```
<a href="/development/html/test1.aspx">This is the LINK to the first page</a>
```

but when I click this link in the second page, it can't find the main page. Here is also the site map xml:

```
 <siteMapNode url="~/development/html/test1.aspx" title="test1"  description="test1">

      <siteMapNode url="~/development/html/test2.aspx" title="test2"  description="test2">
        <siteMapNode url="~/development/html/test1.aspx" title="test1"  description="test1"/>
      </siteMapNode>

    </siteMapNode>
```

I get the following error:

> Server Error in '/' Application. The resource cannot be found.
>   Description: HTTP 404. The resource you are looking for (or one of its
>   dependencies) could have been removed, had its name changed, or is
>   temporarily unavailable.  Please review the following URL and make
>   sure that it is spelled correctly.
>
> Requested URL: /development/html/test1.aspx
>
> Version Information: Microsoft .NET Framework Version:4.0.30319;
>   ASP.NET Version:4.6.1586.0

Comment: When you are on your main page, what URL does the browser's address bar show?

Comment: Look at the difference between your `href` and your `siteMapNode`'s `url` attribute. See the `~`? That's key when using ASP.NET, as it's the "virtual path" you need to worry about.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [use of tilde (~) in asp.net path](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3077558/use-of-tilde-in-asp-net-path)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like your test1.aspx and test2.aspx are in the same folder, so I dont think you have to navigate through your folders. try this:

```
<a href="test1.aspx">text</a>
```

and

```
<a href="test2.aspx">text</a>
```

---

Edit

You can try using response.redirect(); like this:

give your href the runat="server" property:

```
<a href="#" runat="server" onserverclick="goToSecondPage">This is the LINK to the second page</a>
```

And in your C# you can then do :

```
protected void goToSecondPage(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
         Response.Redirect("test2.aspx");
    }
```